# How can I add tracks to "starred" playlist in Spotify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spotify

I'm using [rspotify](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify) gem in my application, I'm able to add tracks in other playlists but not in "starred" playlist. I'm getting 500 Internal server error. Anyone can please let me know how can do this?

I just want to make a track as starred track in spotify, is there any other way using [spotify web api](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) to perform this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotify's Web API doesn't support adding tracks to the Starred list, and it doesn't officially support retrieving Starred tracks. The 500 response status code is a bug - the correct response should be 404 Not Found. Hopefully this will be solved shortly.

Update: The Web API now returns 404 Not Found for attempting to add tracks to the Starred playlist.